# Is there automatic hyphenation in Pages for ios

Tags: ios, pages

Question is very simple, but my web search skills have not been sufficient: Is there automatic hyphenation in Pages on the iPad (with iOS 13.5.1) and if yes, how to turn it on?

My web search did not show up anything (I always get to websites on Pages on the Mac which looks notably different…).

Answer (score 1):

With the current alignment options in Pages, there is no hyphenation option. You can make all lines align their left borders equal and it will allow gaps on the right at the end of a line to continue onto the next line. You can also align your writing so that every line is flush to both the left and right borders. Pages will vary the spacing between words to fit all words on a line.

I've tried both options many times and there is no hyphenation involved. Another option, flush borders on the right will just allow large gaps at the beginning of a line. Again there is no hyphenation.

Comment: Wow, that's a bit disappointing.

Comment: It shouldn't be.  The purpose of hyphenation was to fit a word on the end of a line. If you can respace the earlier words to prevent this from occurring then there is no need for hyphenation.  Did you particularly want hyphenation?

Comment: @Dirk  I don't think Word for iPad has it either.

Comment: @Dirk, you can hyphenate in pages on a Mac, but as far as I can tell not on an iPad. Strange i think.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my spouse and an updated CV.  She added her most current position with Pages under iOS using her iPAD.  The document was FULL of hyphenations.  There is NO way currently to turn Hypenation ON or OFF using Pages for iOS.  I had to Airdrop the document to my MacBook Pro and open it in Pages under macOS.  In Pages on the Mac go to View, Inspector, Document Setup, an in the Inspector on the right hand side, all the way at the bottom under the section for Document Margins. Turn the Check Box for Hyphenation OFF. Save and Close the Document and move it back (using Airdrop) to Pages on the iPad running iOS.
Pages for iOS will now respect the new Global Hyphenation setting.